# Mozilla "Restore previous session" vs Login validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html, login-control

I have a website which rely on a login cookie but when I open the previous session in Mozilla the user is still logged in (b/c the login is not revalidated).

How can I force a reload in this state of my site?

Comment: If you vote please leave a comment here. Thanks

Comment: `previous session in Mozilla` Do you mean valid session cookie? If so, you can use the same session cookie to access the site without relogging in. It is a default behavior in all browsers. What is your concern? *Btw, I didn't cast the close vote.*

Comment: My Concern is that a user which opens the site after Browser close is not the user which has previously logged into the site. And he could might see information which he is not intended to see.

Comment: If 1st user closes *all* browser windows, then the session state is destroyed. It is not possible for 2nd user to view 1st user's information.